# Transferring TFVC pending changes to new branch using VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I currently have a fairly large number of pending changes in TFS. Now, I would like to create a new branch (based on the server version of the code that is the basis for those pending changes) and transfer my pending changes to the new branch.

Google told me about shelving, which I already knew of but don't see how it could help me since I want to transfer the changes to a new base path.

Is there an easier way to transfer the pending changes than manually checking out and copying each file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible to shelve, create a branch and then unshelve to this new branch, by using [TFS Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f):
I found the following passage [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6bx4df3.aspx):

> ...then use the tfpt unshelve command with the /migrate switch:
>
> tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:$/TeamProject/Main
>   /target:$/TeamProject/Beta